# Two-way-binding: editing passed value from XAML control in the model setter does not update control

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-10, uwp

This is for a Windows 10 Universal App.

XAML:

```
<RelativePanel Padding="4" Margin="4,12,0,0">
     <TextBlock x:Name="Label" Text="Class Name" Margin="12,0,0,4"/>
       <ListView x:Name="ClassTextBoxes" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding TextBoxList}" 
                 SelectionMode="None" RelativePanel.Below="Label">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate >
                <RelativePanel>
                  <TextBox x:Name="tbox" 
                       PlaceholderText="{Binding PlaceHolder}" 
                       Text="{Binding BoxText, 
                       Mode=TwoWay,
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                       Padding="4" Width="200" MaxLength="25"/>
                  <TextBlock x:Name="errorLabel" 
                       RelativePanel.Below="tbox"
                       Text="{Binding Error, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       Padding="0,0,0,4"
                       FontSize="10" 
                       Foreground="Red"/>
                  <Button Content="Delete" Margin="12,0,0,0" RelativePanel.RightOf="tbox"/>
              </RelativePanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
</RelativePanel>
```

Model:

```
public class TextBoxStrings : BaseModel
{
    private string _placeholder;
    public string PlaceHolder
    {
        get { return _placeholder; }
        set
        {
            if (_placeholder != value)
            {
                _placeholder = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private string _boxText;
    public string BoxText
    {
        get { return _boxText; }
        set
        {
            if (_boxText != value)
            {
                _boxText = CheckBoxText(value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string CheckBoxText(string val)
    {
        var r = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        return r.Replace(val, "");
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private TrulyObservableCollection<TextBoxStrings> _textBoxList;
public TrulyObservableCollection<TextBoxStrings> TextBoxList
{
        get { return _textBoxList; }
        set
        {
            if (_textBoxList != value)
            {
                _textBoxList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
}
```

and I add new `TextBoxString` objects to my `TextBoxList` collection from within my view-model.

> I want to make it that users can't type in certain characters (or rather, they get deleted whenever they
>   are typed in.

This works...in the model. Setting breakpoints and looking at the values, everything in the Model is working: value goes into the setter and gets changed, `_boxText` holds the new value that is set from `CheckBoxText();`

**But the problem is, in my View, the textbox doesn't reflect changes to the underlying text that I make in the model.**

So if I type in "abc*()" into "tbox", the value in the model will be "abc". The value of the textbox, however, will still be "abc*()".

I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that I'm editing items that are inside of a collection and I don't have anything implemented to handle changing items within a collection. I was under the impression that using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollection<T>` would take care of that for me.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Edit: So, now I'm trying to use `TrulyObservableCollection` because I thought this was the problem, but it hasn't helped. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/itajaja/7507120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the problem is, in my View, the textbox doesn't reflect changes to the underlying text that I make in the model.

As you've seen, the TextBox do reflect changes to your model. When you type in "abc*()" in the TextBox, the value in the model will be changed to "abc". The problem here is that the binding system in UWP is "intelligent". For **TwoWay** bindings, changes to the **target** will automatically propagate to the **source** and in this scenario, binding system assumes that the PropertyChanged event will fire for corresponding property in source and it ignores these events. So even you have `RaisePropertyChanged` or `NotifyPropertyChanged` in you source, the TextBox still won't update.

In WPF, we can call [BindingExpression.UpdateTarget Method](http://BindingExpression.UpdateTarget%20Method%20()) to force the update. But this method is not available in UWP.

As a workaround, you should be able to use [TextBox.TextChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209706) to check the input like following:

```
private void tbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        var originalText = tb.Text;

        var r = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        if (originalText != r.Replace(originalText, ""))
        {
            var index = (tb.SelectionStart - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (tb.SelectionStart - 1);
            tb.Text = r.Replace(originalText, "");
            tb.SelectionStart = index;
        }
    }
}
```

However it may break your MVVM model, you can use **data validation** to avoid this and here is a blog: [Let’s Code! Handling validation in your Windows Store app (WinRT-XAML)](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-handling-validation-in-your.html) you can refer to. And for my personal opinion, data validation is a better direction for this scenario.

Comment: Thank you! I figured I'd come back to this problem eventually, but now I know the solution. Thanks for the link; I think I will go with using Behaviors for now since I already know how to do it. I was actually using behaviors first but thought "wait, just do it in the model!". So I guess I'll have to go back to using behaviors. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should edit `BoxText` and then send checked value to UI. Just send `value` to `CheckBoxText` and *already* edited should be assigned to `_boxText`. And then you should send `BoxText` to UI by calling `RaisePropertyChanged("BoxTest")`. Please, see the following code snippet:

```
private string _boxText;
public string BoxText
{
    get { return _boxText; }
    set
    {
        if (_boxText != value)
        {                    
            _boxText=CheckBoxText(value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("BoxText");
        }
    }
}
```

There is no difference where you use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for one property of for properties placed in collection. The complete example with collections and `ListView` [can be seen here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2087&authkey=!AMXKP8ZAF8YA-JU&ithint=file%2Crar)

Comment: That does not work. I tried doing this, too:

     'set
            {
                if (_boxText != value)
                {
                    var r = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
                    value = r.Replace(value, "");              
                    _boxText = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }

Comment: I'll edit my original post to show what I have now. It is still not working with your suggestions, though.

Comment: Why parameter of `RaisePropertyChanged();` is empty?

Comment: http://10rem.net/blog/2013/02/25/using-callermembername-for-property-change-notification-in-xaml-apps

No need to use the string name.

Comment: @user3007447 It should work and it works. I've made a test example for you: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2086&authkey=!AMpHIUoLU0PHF6o&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: But does your example work if you have the collection in the viewmodel and it represents a collection of model data, like mine? I'll try it and see. You have everything in the viewmodel in your example.

Comment: @user3007447 There is no differences where you use INotifyPropertyChanged for one property of for properties placed in collection. The complete example with collections and `ListView` can be seen here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2087&authkey=!AMXKP8ZAF8YA-JU&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: Yes, your code does work. I must be missing something... Only difference I see is that I am using a UWP app.

Comment: @user3007447 also I see that you are using `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `RaiseProeprtyChanged`. Try to set name explicitly like that `OnPropertyChanged("BoxText")`;

Comment: Yeah, one is for ViewModel, other is for Model. I tried with explicit naming and it did not work. My values are being set correctly. I check with breakpoints. Everything except for the value of the textbox itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (_boxText != value)
{
    _boxText = CheckBoxText(value);
    NotifyPropertyChanged();
}
```

Try changing this to:

```
var tmp = CheckBoxText(value);
if (_boxText != tmp)
{
    _boxText = tmp;
    NotifyPropertyChanged();
}
```

I hope, in your XAML, the binding to property `BoxText` is `two-way`, right?

Comment: Yes, the binding is two-way.Your solution did not work. Maybe the problem is that my collection is in my ViewModel and not the model?

Comment: As far as I know, that's where it should be.